# How to find the sum of two fractions from another sum of given segments?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The problem is as follows:

> Let $\textrm{A, B, C, D and E}$ consecutive points located in a line. It is also known $\textrm{D}$ is midpoint of $\overline{BE}$.
>
> Find $\textrm{AC}$.
>
> Assume:
> $AB\cdot CE=AE\cdot BC$ and
> $15(AE-BD)=2(AE\cdot AB).$

The choices given are:

$\begin{array}{cc}
1.&\textrm{3.5 u}\\
2.&\textrm{5.2 u}\\
3.&\textrm{7.5 u}\\
4.&\textrm{9.2 u}\\
5.&\textrm{13.5 u}\\
\end{array}$

The official answer sheet indicates that the answer for this problem is choice 3.

But I don't know how to solve this.
I attempted to assign variables to the segments but the resulting doesn't help me much.

I tried using in between A, B, C, D and E. Variables a,b,c and d.

Then what it is given above becomes into:

$b+c=d$

$a\cdot (c+d)= (a+b+c+d)\cdot b$

$15(a+b+c+d-(b+c))=2((a+b+c+d))\cdot a$

But from these from above it looks way too much for algebraic manipulation to get what it is requested. I mean this:

$x=a+b$

That's where I got stuck. What to do from here?. Can someone help me please?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let use another designations:
$$AB=a, AC=b, AE=c$$
Then
$$BC=b-a,BE=c-a,CE=c-b,BD=\frac{c-a}2$$
Then statement $15(AE-BD)=2(AE\cdot AB)$ becomes
$$15\left(c-\frac{c-a}2\right)=2ca \Rightarrow (a+c)\frac{15}2=2ac$$
Statement $AB\cdot CE=AE\cdot BC$ becomes
$$a(c-b)=c(b-a)\Rightarrow 2ac=(a+c)b$$
Combining both statements one can get
$$(a+c)\frac{15}2=2ac=(a+c)b \Rightarrow b=\frac{15}2$$